# cannot access value passed from context api in firestore fetch data function

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, react-context

so I am trying to fetch some data from my firestore through the following bit of code

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { CocktailContext } from '../../context/CocktailContext';
import fire, { db } from '../../Config/firebase';
import RecipeCard from '../RecipeCard/RecipeCard';
import NavBar from '../NavBar/NavBar';

export default function SavedItemPage() {
    const [ content, setContent ] = useState(null);
    const { uid } = useContext(CocktailContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        listenForMessages(uid)
    }, []);

    const listenForMessages = (id) => {
        db.collection('users').doc(id).onSnapshot(function(doc) {
            const allMessages = [];
            allMessages.push(doc.data());
            setContent(allMessages);
            console.log(content);
        });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <NavBar />
        </div>
    );
}
```

what should basically happen here is that the context API which looks like below, takes the uid and feeds it into listenForMessages() which then does the job of fetching the content

```
 {
    "name": "State",
    "value": null,
    "subHooks": []
  },
  {
    "name": "Context",
    "value": {
      "recipes": "[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]",
      "searchTerm": "ƒ searchTerm() {}",
      "updateUid": "ƒ updateUid() {}",
      "uid": "MfLXrE5czaYK7fYiTFuqFv9SZV02"
    },
    "subHooks": []
  },
  {
    "name": "Effect",
    "value": "ƒ () {}",
    "subHooks": []
  }
]
```

trouble is that when the page loads i am met with this errors- FirebaseError: Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: ""

so the trouble is that  listenForMessages() is not able to access the uid value in the context API.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Firebase works, but the useContext maybe is incorrect ?
usually you use it this way :

```
[state, dispatch] = useContext(CocktailContext)
```

Which will give you the whole state. In the state you provided there is 3 objects in your state so i guess you will access the uid by doing something like:

```
    useEffect(() => listenForMessages(state[1].value.uid));
```

I see there is a ' ] ' closing your provided state but nothing at the beginning, just adapt in case i miss a node level.